# Remove or reverse file redirection in group policy

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy, folder-redirection

I am looking for a way to essentially reverse file and folder redirection after it has been set up and configured using Group Policy.

Right now I have a file server that I am hanging a file share off to enable network storage for the redirected profiles.  In my testing so far, everything is working correctly with my file and folder redirection setup.

What I would like to be able to do is copy down all of the contents from the network redirected shares back to the local computer for a given user, is this possible?  Or is it a one way street?  I have followed the steps from numerous guides to reverse the file and folder redirection process but I am still unable to get this to work.

**More Details:**

Here is an example of what the File and Folder Group Policy looks like.  As I said this is working correctly.

[image]

I have set up a new policy which I am applying to the given OU to apply the local profile and folder redirection back to the PC.  Here is what it looks like.

[image]

I'm getting the impression that this will help by pointing all the file and folder locations but I still have to manually copy the files housed on the network share back to the computer.  Can somebody confirm?  Is there a way to automatically get the copy working?

Comment: You have to REMOVE the policy in order to restore the files to their original location. That's why it's called "Policy Removal Behavior".

Comment: Yes I have tried this and it doesn't seem to have an effect.  I am going to build out some more test users and see if I can get the intended effect.

Comment: I think I know part of the problem.  It looks like my permissions on the file share are all jacked up, I will fix them and then update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check your permissions against the process listed in this post.  The post is outdated but as far as I know setup is the same on Server 2008 R2.  I have this configured on my Windows boxes and when I remove the GPO data is automatically directed back to the local machine.  Since the GPO settings are all correct my money is on permissions.  I would also check the event viewer on the server and the client.  I would imaging an error occurred at some point that should shed some light on where the issue is located.

[Automatic creation of user folders for home, roaming profile and redirected folders | Microsoft Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/30/automatic-creation-of-user-folders-for-home-roaming-profile-and-redirected-folders.aspx)

Comment: You are right on the money.  It was a permissions thing.